# Sprite only partially shown

Tags: css, performance, stylesheet, sprite, css-sprites

I attempted to make a sprite image for the bottom of my asp.net home page, to reduce the number of http requests.  I looked at all the coding, and can't find any errors.  Here is the image:

[image: 5 social media buttons]

But for some reason, my google+ image doesn't show up; it only shows 4 of the 5 social media buttons.  Here is the jsfiddle, which doesn't show the google+ button also:

[JSFiddle - social media buttons](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonpaulweber/R8Eu8/)

Thank you for anybody who can offer any guidance in this regard!

SE wants me to include code in here, although it's on the Fiddle.  But anyway, here is what I have in my stylesheet:

```
.homepage{
width:23px;
height:23px;
background-image: url(http://www.ussvision.com/images/sprite-homepage.jpg); 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.fbook{
background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.twit{
background-position: -25px 0px;
}
.yt{
background-position: -50px 0px;
}
.goog{
background-position: -103px 0px;
}
.linked{
background-position: -150px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The position of .goog should be `-75px 0px`: see http://jsfiddle.net/R8Eu8/1/

Edit: and .linked should be `-103px, 0px`.

Comment: Thank you @Lukas_Skywalker!  I feel pretty dumb right now -- I didn't even see that error.  I definitely appreciate the time to read and respond to my question, and post your fiddle.  Thank you very much!